# Change admin logout URL

Tags: admin, urls

My site is using a short vanity URL. This is working across all of the custom theme pages. The only problem is when I logout in the admin it redirects to the long URL, which then 404s.

My General Settings (which I can't change) are:

WordPress address (URL): The long URL
Site address (URL): The short URL

Looks like the logout link is generated from wp-includes/general-template.php, but I hate to edit core, non-theme, WordPress files.

Any ideas how to solve this logout 404 problem is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quickest way to do this is through an Apache rewrite via [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html). You'll also have to tell WordPress where to points its login links using the [login_url](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/login_url?version=3.1&file=wp-includes/general-template.php) and [logout_url](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/logout_url?version=3.1&file=wp-includes/general-template.php) filters.

```
  return apply_filters('login_url', $login_url, $redirect);
  return apply_filters('logout_url', $logout_url, $redirect);
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what do to to Apache - do I add something to my htaccess file? The login link works fine, so do I only need to edit the logout link (which currently 404s)? I will add your example to my general-template.php file and edited it to include the logout URL. Is this correct: return apply_filters('logout_url', $logout_url, wp-login.php?loggedout=true);

Comment: No that's not correct. Those apply_filters lines are what WordPress is executing. You'll want to `add_filter` via an `add_filter('logout_url', 'function_name');` and have `function_name` look something like `function_name($logout_url, $redirect) { return "http://new.login/link.html"; }` or whatever works to alter the $logout_url. Do this in a "must use" plugin (background via hakre: http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/must-use-and-drop-ins-plugins/) or maybe via functions.php in your theme folder.

Comment: Getting there - In my admin, in place of the log in/out buttons is the error "Missing argument 2 for logout_fix." I couldn't find a plugin from your URL so I added this code to functions.php: http://pastebin.com/QNPWTjs1

Comment: You sure are getting your money's worth out of me. I see you keep accepting and unaccepting my answer to pump me for additional answers! When you add_filter, try using the 2 extra parameters in `add_filter().` The first is the priority, set that to zero (highest). The second is the number of arguments, which is two. Maybe `add_filter('logout_url', 'function_name', 0, 2);`

Comment: Sorry - I thought your answer would work but it didn't and I'm desperate :) Will mark once this is resolved I promise! OK, so the extra 2 params did change the logout URL. However, I'm not able to actually logout. If I try returning "http://domain.com/wp-login.php?action=logout" it asks me if I want to logout; clicking yes results in an endless "WordPress failure notice" loop. If I return "http://domain.com/wp-login.php?loggedout=true" nothing happens. What do I need to change the URL to to logout?

Comment: I thought you were doing an Apache rewrite on the logout link? It doesn't sound like that's happening.

Comment: I'm confused as to what exactly to do with Apache (from my first comment). The only thing I've added is the function & add_filter to the functions.php file. What else needs to be done? Thanks.

Comment: xx The quickest way to do this is through an Apache rewrite via mod_rewrite. xx

Comment: How exactly do I do that? Do I edit my .htaccess file? If so, what exactly do I add to it? Thank you.

Comment: Once I read this comment thread I felt morally obligated to upvote @editor .